# Can't insert data into oracle sql with php

Tags: php, oracle

ok so i can connect and view the database with my php code, however i can't put data into it. here's a query I tested with oracle db that can insert new data into my table.

```
$qSave = oci_parse($c1, "INSERT INTO WA_TKP_TBL_PART (FORM_NO, CUSTOMERID_FK, MAKER_PART_CODE, SUPPLIERID_FK, MAKERID_FK, DESCRIPTION,
                        MSDS_FILE, ROHS2_FILE, TDS_FILE, DATEADDED, ADDEDBY, ISSUE_DATE, EXPIRE_DATE, ISO_9001_EXPIRE_DATE, ISO_14001_EXPIRE_DATE, EVIDENCE_FILE, ISO_FILE) VALUES(
                            '$new_id', '$getCustomer', '$getMakerPartCodeC', '$getSupplier', '$getMaker', '$getDescriptionC',
                            '$newname3', '$newname4', '$newname2', TO_DATE('$date_added', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), '$getUserID', TO_DATE('$getIssueDate', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), TO_DATE('$getExpireDate', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),TO_DATE('$iso9001Expired', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),TO_DATE('$iso14001Expired', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), '$newname6', '$newname7')");
                        
oci_execute($qSave);
                        
if($qSave)
{
    $qChkLastIDN = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY WHERE TO_CHAR(ACTIVITYDATE, 'YYYY-MON') = '$date_codeFormat'");
    oci_execute($qChkLastIDN);
    if(oci_fetch($qChkLastIDN) > 0)
    {
        $qGetLastIDN = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY ORDER BY ACTIVITYID DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1 AND TO_CHAR(ACTIVITYDATE, 'YYYY-MON') = '$date_codeFormat'");
        oci_execute($qGetLastIDN);
        $dGetLastIDN = oci_fetch_array($qGetLastIDN);
                                
        $getLastIDN = $dGetLastIDN['ACTIVITYID'];
        $cutGetLastIDN = substr($getLastIDN, 8);
                                
        $id_numN = substr($getLastIDN, 8) + 1;
        $id_numN = str_pad($id_numN, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $dateCode = date("Ym");
        $id_letterN = "AC".$dateCode;

        $new_idN = $id_letterN . $id_numN;
    }
    $qCustomer = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_GA_TBL_CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMERID = '" . $getCustomer . "'");
    oci_execute($qCustomer);
    $dCustomer = oci_fetch_array($qCustomer);
    $getCustomerName = $dCustomer['CUSTOMER_NAME'];
                            
    $qSupplier = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_GA_TBL_SUPPLIER WHERE SUPPLIERID = '" . $getSupplier . "'");
    oci_execute($qSupplier);
    $dSupplier = oci_fetch_array($qSupplier);
    $getSupplierName = $dSupplier['SUPPLIER_NAME'];
                            
    $qMaker = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_GA_TBL_MAKER WHERE MAKERID = '" . $getMaker . "'");
    oci_execute($qMaker);
    $dMaker = oci_fetch_array($qMaker);
    $getMakerName = $dMaker['MAKER_NAME'];
                            
    $getResult = "partAdded";
}
```

Comment: You need to add error checking, and print the error message if it fails.

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL-injection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500572/how-to-use-prepared-statements-and-bound-parameters-in-php-oci8 for how to use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: `if($qSave)` is not the way to check if the insert was successful. You need to test the result of `oci_execute()`.

Comment: So, what does "can't insert" actually mean? Code runs but does nothing? Or there's an error? If so, which one?